# How to align text by Linux command prompt?

Tags: linux, command, text-align

I have a text file and then I want to align it. 
I used `column -t myfile > newfile.`
 But this command delete an empty line which separated two sentences. How can I do now? Please help me.

```
Myfile: a c                Used column -t : a   c      Desired file: a    c
        bd e                                bd  e                    bd   e
        .                                   .                        .
                                            f   g                     
        f g                                 hi  j                    f    g
        hi j                                                         hi   j
```

Comment: you might use `awk`. Notice that `fmt` could reformat your texte.

Comment: Please help me with more details, Basile? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`column -e -t myfile > newfile`.

`-e` is the option for 'Do not ignore empty lines'.

If the `-e` option is not available -- it appears to be patched in by Debian and derivatives, so may not be available on other systems -- a kludge is:

`sed -e 's/^$/###xxx###/' myfile | column -t | sed -e 's/###xxx###//'`

where `###xxx###` is a string you would not expect to see anywhere in your file.  Blank lines are filled by `sed` with this string before they hit the `column` command, which stops them being silently dropped.  Following the `column` command, the odd string is removed by `sed`.

Comment: Thanks Tony, but it's noticed that column: unknown option --e  :'(

Comment: Can you check that you have just one dash before the e, and if it still doesn't work, advise which system you are using (including version)?  The `-e` option works for perfectly for me with the example file that you have provided.

Comment: @Alice, please see edits above, which provide a workaround for systems that don't have the `-e` option.

Comment: Thanks Tony, but I still do not find the right way. The command prompt said that: unknown option 's'. I used Cygwin.
P/S: I used just one dash before the e but not work.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm at a loss.  I cannot understand why the longer command (`sed...column...sed`) would fail if entered exactly as above.

Comment: Oh, I try it again and it worked well. So sorry Tony, maybe I took some mistakes in typing. Many thanks Tony. Have a nice day. :D